# How to optimize Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby method

```
def get_status(creds)
  client = create_client(creds)
  status = client.account_status
  client.close_session
  status
end
```

Usually, I optimize this kind of code by `tap` or `yield_self`, but here I can't find a nice way to optimize it.

The only solution I have come up:

```
def get_status(creds)
  create_client(creds).yeild_self do |client|
    [client, client.account_status]
  end.yield_self do |client, status|
    client.close_session
    status
  end
end
```

But it doesn't better than the original solution, is it?

Comment: Can you give a clear, unambiguous, precise, objectively measurable definition of what you mean by "better"? What is and isn't "better" is generally based on subjective opinions, which makes questions about "better" off-topic unless "better" is precisely defined. Same applies to "optimized". There are many things to optimize: memory usage, runtime, throughput, latency, cold-cache startup time, warm-cache startup time, … Also, if your code *works* and you are asking for improvements, then [codereview.se] is generally better equipped for that than [so]. Make sure to study their help center first.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I guess everybody has their own understanding of better, I just want to see it. You're right, I should move it to Code Review.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, btw I can't choose the right site coz the list `Closing ->Community specific` doesn't have `Code Review` option

Comment: There's a very good reason non-moderators can't select Code Review from that list, the amount of rejected migrations would be immense.

Comment: If you move/repost this on Code Review, make sure you pick a descriptive title and add a description of what the code actually does. Stack Overflow focuses on short MCVEs, Code Review requires context. See [the guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915).

Comment: IMHO the first version is much better than the second. It is shorter, easier to read, and easier to understand. I see no reason to change it.

Comment: Consider creating a separate class with a finalizer that closes the session. Then simply return the account_status, and when the object goes out of scope it will automatically call close_session.

Comment: @Matt, are you referring to the use of [ObjectSpace::define_finalizer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer), a method I had not seen before?

Comment: @Matt, that is what I was looking for, please write your idea as an answer so I can star it, thanks

Comment: The tricky thing with a finalizer is that you can't access the object itself in the finalizer, since it may have already been destroyed, but you do have access to its `object_id`. If you can save everything you need about an object in order to `close_session` on it into a class hash variable while it is instantiated, then you can retrieve it based on the `object_id` in the finalizer. If Cary or anyone else wants to do this, please give the credit to them instead. Personally I would stick to your first version.

Comment: @Matt It's not that it may have been destroyed; it's that it _can't_ be destroyed. If you reference the object in a finalizer, it gets closed over, and a reference is kept in the closure; the reference will never disappear, which prevents the garbage collector to clean it up, and thus the finalizer never runs. Finalizers are awesome for libraries, giving the end users some security from common bugs like not closing resources; but are usually overkill for users' own non-library code unless the app is large.

Comment: @Amadan Interesting point. However I am skeptical of your comment: "and thus the finalizer never runs." Here is a counter-example: `def test
  foo = 'test'
  ObjectSpace.define_finalizer foo, proc { puts "Finalizing #{foo}" }
end

test` Output: `Finalizing test`. The object `foo` is referenced in the finalizer, yet the finalizer is run nonetheless.

Comment: @Matt [See commented demo on repl.it](https://repl.it/@GoranTopic/SpiffyPrettyMicroinstruction#main.rb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could write the following.

```
class Client
  def account_status
    "Overdrawn!"
  end
  def close_session
    puts "It's closed"
  end
end
```

```
def create_client(creds)
  Client.new
end
```

```
def get_status(creds)
  begin
    client = create_client(creds)
    client.account_status
  ensure
    client.close_session if client
  end
end
```

```
get_status("Anything")
It's closed
  #=> "Overdrawn!"
```

Do I prefer this to #1 in the question? No.

Do I prefer this to #2 in the question? Yes!

Do I prefer this to @max's answer? No.

---

I understand a *finalizer* could be created using the class method [ObjectSpace::define_finalizer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer).

```
class Client
  def initialize
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, proc { puts "It's finalized!" })
  end

  def account_status
    "Overdrawn!"
  end
end
```

```
def create_client(creds)
  Client.new
end
```

```
def get_status(creds)
  create_client(creds).account_status
end
```

```
get_status("Anything")
  #=> "Overdrawn!" 
exit
It's finalized!
```

One must be careful when creating finalizers, as explained [Here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch08s07.html). I understand a technique sometimes used is to have `finalizer`'s proc reference class-level objects. See, for example, [this article](https://www.mikeperham.com/2010/02/24/the-trouble-with-ruby-finalizers/), @Amadan's comments below and @Matt's comments on the question. I am not advocating the use of a finalizer. I merely thought readers unfamiliar with finalizers (as I was before writing this) would find this useful.

Comment: I disagree. Change `client.close_session` to `client.close_session if client` or `client&.close_session`, and I'll prefer this version over others - if a connection is opened, it should be closed, and there are only two ways to guarantee it: `ensure`, or a finalizer (and if `client` cleans up in a finalizer, then `#close_session` is noise).

Comment: I just saw @Matt's comment. Yes, finalizer is superior. But a) it is notoriously tricky to get right, and b) the `client` class might not be under your control, and maybe you don't want to make a wrapper, or monkeypatch it.

Comment: See my example for finalizers in question comments - creating a `proc` inside an instance method captures the instance into the closure, even if you don't use it, causing a memory leak. "Notoriously tricky". :) The article you linked suggests the same technique I used: create the `proc` inside a class method.

Answer (score 2):

Let's list the goal of the function:

1. Open connection
2. Read value (and return it)
3. Close connection

I would consider this a "temporary connection", and that leads me to think it could be refactored to a separate method.

Reasoning: The `get_status` method is concerned with getting the status from a connection - it doesn't have to handle the details of actually closing/opening the connection itself.

```
def open_temporary_connection(creds, &block)
  client = create_client(creds)
  result = block.call(client)
  client.close_session
  result
end

def get_status(creds)
  open_temporary_connection(creds, &:account_status)
end
```

Also, I should mention, I think `yield_self` is a bit of a trap. Unless you're dead set on making all of your code into a single expression, it makes the code look awkward without offering a lot of benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I like your first version because it is short, easy to read, and easy to understand. I would not change it.

Nevertheless, an alternative version using `tap` might look like this:

```
def get_status(creds)
  client = create_client(creds)
  client.account_status.tap { client.close_session }
end
```